# Logging in to a website, second time does not return cookie hash key?

Tags: c#, cookies, web

I'm programmatically logging in to a website, using HttpWebRequest, POST method. The first time I successfully authenticate, via HttpWebResponse I receive cookie hash key. The second time I perform the same action, I don't receive it anymore.

Does that mean I'm already "Logged in", or does it store my session somewhere, I don't quite understand it, if someone could explain, thank you!

**Here's my code and simply said, running this twice, do not return same cookie result.**

```
        HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");

        string cookie = string.Empty;
        string values = "vb_login_username=" + username + "&vb_login_password=" + password + "securitytoken=guest&" + "cookieuser=checked&" + "do=login";

        http.Method = "POST";
        http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        http.ContentLength = values.Length;

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        http.CookieContainer = cookies;

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;


        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(http.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            stream.Write(values);
        }



        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();

        foreach (var c in response.Cookies)
        {
            cookie = cookie + c.ToString() + ";";
        }

        return cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

The second time, you have likely provided the cookie yourself in your HTTP request, so the server does not send you the cookie again.

Use the development tools (F12) in IE and send the same requests there, monitoring the Network tab (you need to press the green triangle to start monitoring). You will be able to drill in and see what was included in each request and response.

There are also ways to trace the network traffic your program is generating, but there's a bit more setup than just opening IE.